# HTML text rendered backwards... but only partially (1., 2., etc.)

Tags: html, css

When text inside of an  tag is rendered with a preceding number, the number is sent to the back of the string, and its punctuation is rendered backwards.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">1. Step One</a>
```

**Renders as:**

```
 Step One .1
```

This might be weird to try and imagine, so I have included a link to the screenshot:

**HTML, CSS, & Rendered result:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRmcV.jpg

I'm at a bit of a loss for what could possibly cause this. My theory is that there is some CSS property being inherited from elsewhere. I have been slowly removing chunks of CSS in an effort to find the guilty party, but so far no luck. This renders 100% properly on other sections of the website that use different style sheets. I was not the original author of the style sheets, so it has been difficult to pin-point the possible source.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone has seen anything similar and might be able to point me in the direction of CSS properties that could possibly cause this, or if it's something else entirely.

Comment: What is your css code?  do you have any RTL  (right to left) commands?

Comment: Alternatively to CSS, look for `dir="rtl"` attributes in your HTML source.

Comment: Have you tried your browser developer tools? They will tell you exactly which css is used for a particular element.

Comment: @briansol I can post the CSS directly related to these elements, but on a page with no other style sheets it is rendering properly. Trying to dig through all other CSS above this has been a headache and probably not a good idea to dump. I know it's not ideal, but I'm not aware of much of an alternative. I am open to suggestions, of course!

Comment: @Tomalak none of my current HTML has it. I appreciate the idea though!

Comment: @the_lotus in the screenshot, the computed css is taken from dev tools. I believe there is some css affecting the rest of the page (not just directly these elements) that is causing. There is nothing particularly un-ordinary about the styles you see on the computed, as well as the broken-out styles.

Comment: @veratti Use the "computed style" tab to track down any `text-direction` that might be in effect for your element in question. It will point you to the exact location of the responsible CSS file.

Comment: @Tomalak you were correct about that property being the culprit (direction: rtl)! I was able to find that the CSS property with your guidance, you are my hero - I had seen posts about the attribute on the element, but didn't think to look for "direction" in the CSS. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @briansol I realize in hindsight that you meant css RTL - I apologize for assuming you were talking about the HTML attribute. Thank you for your help, you were correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you **@Tomalak**, **@briansol** and **@the_lotus** for helping me track this one down.

There was a CSS property being inherited that was causing the text to render this way. Upon viewing *inherited* computed styles, I saw:

```
direction: rtl;
```

The correct property setting would be:

```
direction: ltr;
```

Thanks again for your help!